# Changing Key name in mongodb based on its value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of a element `element_list=['A','C']` and my document in mongodb is like:

```
"product_id": {
    "$oid": "AA"
},
"output": [
    {
        "product": {
            "$oid": "A"
        },
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "$oid": "B"
        },
        "value": 1
    },
]
}
```

what I want is based on my `element_list` value the key should change like:

```
"product_id": {
    "$oid": "AA"
},
"products": [
    {
        "product": {
            "$oid": "A"
        },
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "Offer": {
            "$oid": "B"
        },
        "value": 1
    },
]
}
```

`'B'` is not present in `element_list`, that's why its key is `Offer`. How to automatically update multiple similar documents in python?

Comment: Please explain what is the expected change and what is the criteria for a change. How can I tell that 'B is not presented' ? By $oid?

Comment: This was my actual question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102616/inserting-nested-dictionary-in-mongodb-in-given-format) i tried multiple approach to insert in mongodb the best result which i got is i posted that in this question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
oids = set([e['product_id']['$oid'] for e in data])
for product in data:
    new_products = []
    for output in product['output']:
        key = 'Offer' if output['product']['$oid'] not in oids else 'product'
        new_products.append({key: {'$oid': output['product']['$oid'], 'value': output['value']}})
    product['products'] = new_products
    del product['output']
print(data)
```